# Как сгенерировать Biginteger заданного размера?

Tags: c#

Как можно сгенерировать число Biginteger заданного размера?

Comment: Что значит заданного размера?

Comment: К примеру, числа 64,128 бит

Comment: вот есть конструктор с массивом байт: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Numerics_BigInteger__ctor_System_Byte___

Comment: Вам это не нужно, `BigInteger` сам регулирует свой размер